# Facebook Logout logout problems when using subdomains

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am working on a website that uses multiple subdomains.

If I login on `www.mysite.com` and then switch to `news.mysite.com` the login status works fine.

However, if I call `FB.logout` while on `news.mysite.com` I'm am logged out fine. I can go to any page on that subdomain and remained logged out. I can even go to a new subdomain and remain logged out, for example, `review.mysite.com`.

However, if I go back to `www.mysite.com` I am logged back in again and the login persists across all subdomains.

Is this an issue with Facebook? If so, is there a workaround? Could it be a bug in my code?

Comment: Just found this question. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7206204/new-js-sdk-with-oauth-2-0-saving-subdomain-in-fbsr-cookie

my question is a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think if you add/edit the domain name mysite.com as **"App Domain"** in application settings page in http://facebook.com/developers (and/or specifying the child domains as well) will fix the issue.

Comment: I have the App Domain set to mysite.com already. I thought that.